# A question on identification

Tags: probability, panel-data, identifiability

This question is about how to show **identification of the fixed effects in a static panel linear model**.

**A1 (model):** The model is
$$
Y_{it}=\alpha_i+X_{it}^\top \beta+\epsilon_{it}  
$$
for each $i=1,...,N$ and $t=1,...,T$, where $i$ indexes individuals and $t$ indexes time periods.

**A2 (data):** We assume to have an i.i.d. sample of $N$ observations $\{Y_{i1}, X_{i1},\dots, Y_{iT}, X_{iT}\}_{i=1}^N$ with $N$ large.

**A3 (exogeneity):** $E(\epsilon_{it}| X_{i1},..., X_{iT}, \alpha_i)=0$ for each $t=1,...,T$ and $i=1,...,N$.

**Question:**  In the so called "fixed effect model", $\alpha_1,..., \alpha_N$ are treated as parameters (together with $\beta$) and possibly estimated. How can we show that $(\alpha_1,..., \alpha_N, \beta)$ are identified under A1, A2, A3?

**Remark:** I think that $T$ large is also needed to identify $\alpha_1,..., \alpha_N$. Feel free to add this assumption.

---

**My thoughts and doubts:**

I have found several sources discussing how to estimate $(\alpha_1,..., \alpha_N, \beta)$ or how to identify/estimate $\beta$ alone (by differencing out $\alpha_1,..., \alpha_N$), but no papers or books explaining the joint identification of $(\alpha_1,..., \alpha_N, \beta)$.

I'm aware of the **incidental parameter problem** which prevents consistent estimation of $(\alpha_1,..., \alpha_N)$ when $T$ is fixed and  $N\rightarrow \infty$. Hence, I suppose that $(\alpha_1,..., \alpha_N)$  are not identified when $T$ is fixed and $N\rightarrow \infty$. The incidental parameter problem disappears if we also let $T\rightarrow \infty$. Does this imply that identification of  $(\alpha_1,..., \alpha_N)$  can be established? How?

In what follows,  I report my incomplete attempt.

$Y_i\equiv (Y_{i1},..., Y_{iT})$ and $X_i\equiv (X_{i1},..., X_{iT})$. $K$ is the size of $\beta$. I assume $NT>  N+K$.

First, I rewrite the model as
$$
Y_{it}=\sum_{\ell=1}^N\alpha_l 1\{i=\ell\}+X_{it}^\top \beta+\epsilon_{it}, 
$$
where I consider $\alpha_1,..., \alpha_N$ as parameters and the index $i$ as a random variable. Second, I rewrite A3
$$
E(\epsilon_{it}| i, X_{i1},..., X_{iT})=0, 
$$
for each $i=1,...,N$ and $t=1,...,T$.

By A3, for each   $i=1,\dots, N$, there exists a realisation  of the $T\times K $ matrix $X_{i}\equiv (X_{i1},..., X_{iT})$ (which I denote by $x_{i}\equiv (x_{i1},..., x_{iT})$) such that
$$
\begin{cases}
E(\epsilon_{i1}|i=1, X_{i} =x_1)=0 \\
\vdots\\
E(\epsilon_{iT}|i=1,  X_{i} =x_1 )=0 \\
\vdots\\
E(\epsilon_{i1}|i=N,  X_{i} =x_N )=0 \\
\vdots\\
E(\epsilon_{iT}|i=N, X_{i} =x_N )=0 \\
\end{cases} 
$$
In turn, by A1,
$$
\begin{cases}
E(Y_{i1}|i=1, X_{i} =x_1 )=\alpha_1+\beta x_{11} \\
\vdots\\
E(Y_{iT}|i=1, X_{i} =x_1 )=\alpha_1+\beta x_{1T} \\
\vdots\\
E(Y_{i1}|i=N, X_{i} =x_N )=\alpha_N+\beta x_{N1} \\
\vdots\\
E(Y_{iT}|i=N, X_{i} =x_N )=\alpha_N+\beta x_{NT} \\
\end{cases} 
$$
I can more compactly rewrite this system of equations as
$$
\underbrace{Y}_{NT\times 1}=\overbrace{\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
D & X
\end{pmatrix}}_{NT \times (N+K)}}^{\equiv \Gamma} \overbrace{\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha \\
\beta
\end{pmatrix}}_{(N+K)\times 1}}^{\equiv \phi}. 
$$
Next,
$$
\Gamma^\top Y= \Gamma^\top \Gamma \phi. 
$$
Thus,
$$
\phi=(\Gamma^\top \Gamma)^{-1}  \Gamma^\top Y 
$$
under the assumption that $\Gamma^\top \Gamma$ is invertible.

I would be done with the proof if I could claim that $Y$ is known for $N$ large under assumption A1. I don't think this is the case, though. I suppose that somehow we also need large $T$, but I don't see clearly how.

Comment: There are a number of problem here. To begin with, the term identifiability is normally used in such a way that parameters are identifiable if the models parametrised by them are different. This is the case for your $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_N$. The incidental parameter problem says that you can't estimate them consistently, which is possible even if they are identifiable.

Comment: You will need some assumptions about the $X$. Some would have the $X$ so that their first row is constant 1, so the forst component in $\beta$ is an intercept. If this is the case, the $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_N$ are *not* identifiable but confounded with the intercept, and you'd need an additional condition that they sum up to zero (for example). Generally $X$ could be chosen so that there are identifiability problems and conditions are needed to forbid this.

Comment: Generally both identifiability and the existence of consistent estimators deal with the model assuming that potentially infinitely many observations can be had, rather than a finite sample. So "$N$ large" or "$T$ large" won't help proving anything. If something doesn't work for finite $N$ or $T$, asking them to be "large" won't help. However if the model allows $N\to\infty$, say, you don't need to be concerned about finite $N$.

Comment: "First, I rewrite the model..." - I think that using $i$ as a random variable will not lead to anything good. If you have $i$ running from 1 to $N$, you're explicitly saying that it isn't random, aren't you? (I suspect you don't need its randomness anyway.)

Comment: Can't edit the first comment anymore, but you'll see this was imprecise. $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_N$ are not automatically identifiable here, you'll require conditions on the $X$ for this. Just to be in line with the second comment.

Comment: Note by the way that identifiability does *not* imply the existence of a consistent estimator, but the existence of a consistent estimator implies identifiability. Meaning that if you have seen something in the literature that gives you consistent estimators, you are done with identifiability.

Comment: If I see things correctly, $D$ is not defined.

Comment: You don't say clearly whether the $X$ are fixed or random. Chances are you want them fixed? But this is in contradiction to your later notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your $D$ is what I think it is, and taking into account the comments I made regarding the use of terminology and notation, then the additional assumption about $X$ I mentioned in the comments is just that $\Gamma^T\Gamma$ is invertible, which you figured out yourself. (It is not quite that trivial to find out what this means for your $X$ though. Large $N$ and $T$ may make it easier to fulfill this.)

What may be confusing is that you used $Y$ in the last equations for a vector that actually has the *expected values* of the $Y_{it}$ rather than the $Y_{it}$ themselves. The latter are random and not known, whereas the former are defined in the model framework. So you're basically done.

Note that for identifiability the $N$ and $T$ can be taken as fixed, however, as identifiability is about the model and *not* about a fixed sample, implicitly this assumes an infinite number of realisations of any $\epsilon_{it}$, or rather, more precisely and clearly, knowledge of the full distribution of $\epsilon_{it}$ (which carries all the randomness - I'm assuming that you treat the $X$ as fixed, otherwise you'd have to worry about identifying their distribution, too). This may look counterintuitive to you as you may interpret $N$ and $T$ as some kinds of sample sizes that potentially can go to $\infty$. In fact you need $T\to\infty$ (and some further conditions on $X$!) to have a consistent estimator (which as I wrote before is stronger than identifiability). Note that $N\to\infty$ will increase the number of $\alpha$-parameters, so not only will you have more observations at your disposal, you will also have to estimate more parameters, and this is not a standard identifiability problem. (It may however help with estimating $\beta$.)

Comment: Thank you for all your comments. Just a few clarifications (in line with your insights): 1) $X$ does not contain an intercept term. 2) $D$ is an $NT\times  N$ matrix stacking for each $i$ a $T\times N$ matrix with  $i$-th column of ones and the other elements equal to zero. My understanding from your answer is that   $\Gamma^\top \Gamma$  should be invertible for identifiability.

Comment: I still have two fundamental doubts. (A) Identifiability is roughly "being able to  uniquely pin down the parameters (and here I'm mostly interested in the $\alpha$'s) from knowing the distribution of the data (or some of its moments)". My first question is:  how can I know the LHS quantities in my system  without observing each unit $i$ many many times? (B) My second question is:  couldn't I repeat my proof with a weaker exogeneity condition, i.e. $E(\epsilon_{it}| i, X_{it})=0$ for each $i$ and $t$?

Comment: "My understanding from your answer is that $\Gamma^T\Gamma$ should be invertible for identifiability." Yes exactly. (A) Identifiability does *not* involve what you observe. Identifiability (at least according to its standard definition) means that two different parameters do not parametrise the same model. That the parameters are in this way identifiable does *not* necessarily imply that you can observe them in practice.

Comment: (B) The conditioning in these conditions is technically wrong because nothing on which you "condition" is actually a random variable. Unless $X$ is random (in which case the whole thing becomes more complicated), $\epsilon_{it}$ are the *only* random variables here,  and $E(\epsilon_{it})=0$ is all you need.

Comment: I repeat myself but a key thing to understand is that the existence of consistent estimators (which is not possible for finite $T$ due to the incidental parameters problem) is *not* the same as identifiability, but rather a *stronger* property of a parameter that requires stronger conditions.

Comment: Thanks. Is it correct to say that in this setting $Y_1,..., Y_N$ are not identically distributed?

Comment: Yes, unless the $\alpha_i+X_{it}^T\beta$ are the same for all $i$.